# How to deploy new build pipeline data into azure app service root sub folder without removing the previous deployment data

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-appservice

I've created a build and release pipelines, and deployed the react application into azure app service. The application files are available in site/wwwroot path then i created nww build and release pipeline for another react application. when i tried to deploy the new application into previous app service and the path is site/wwwroor/subfolder but new deploy application is replacing the exising appkication. I can able see newly deployed data only previous data is deleted.

I want both application data like

1. first application data in site/wwwroot folder
2. new application data in site/wwwroot/subfolder

How can i achieve this?

Comment: I think it's an usual pattern. Do you want to provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

Create azure web app and create a folder in site\wwwroot\ and add this path in virtual apps in path mappings as shown below. I have named a subfolder as testfolder. The full path will be site\wwwroot\testfolder.
[image]

Next in release pipelines, Azure app service deploy task > Additional deployment Options > Additional arguments, add `-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=wwwroot`.
[image]

**Add this in both the release pipelines** and set virtual app in second release pipeline.
[image]

Create release for app1 and verify the site\wwwroot folder in app service kudu portal.
[image]

[App01](https://i.imgur.com/fX4tbBq.png)

Now create a release for app2 and verify the site\wwwroot\testfolder folder in app service kudu portal.
[image]

[App02](https://i.imgur.com/uOThFgJ.png)

In the above screenshot, test folder is the secondary app created in step 1. After this configuration, no files will get removed in `wwwroot` folder whenever a new deployment is happend.